# GET in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to use retrofit but I am not able to figure out how do I use the @GET() to do the following
I have two 1). url1 :www.url.com/a/b and 2). url2: [www.url.com/c/d](http://www.url.com/c/d)
I have set the base url as [www.url.com](http://www.url.com) but I am not able to figure out how do I set the rest of the url in @get method

```
public interface API {

    @GET(details1)
    Call<Response1> List1();
    @GET(details2)
    Call<Response2> List2();
```

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/13639/retrofit-android-example-tutorial Follow this tutorial and run the sample first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you should put your base URL in Retrofit instance like this :

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl("https://www.url.com /")
.build();
```

And then continue the link here:

```
@GET("c/d")
Call<Response1> getResponse1();
```

I also suggest you read this [link](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)